# How to remove the "mystartsearch" browser redirect malware?

Tags: malware-removal

I keep deleting the search engine on Firefox, yet every time I restart Firefox it shows up again.

I am setting Google as default.

How can I remove "mystartsearch"?

This is not something similar with removing virus. This is removing annoying setting that don't get off the easy way. And I already know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click about:config in firefox.

Search for startsearch

You will see a bunch of entries. Reset them.